# Bound on the eigenvalues of product of a diagonal matrix and a positive semi-definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $D \in R^{n \times n}$ be a diagonal metric with strictly positive coefficients and $S \in R^{n \times n}$ a positive semi-definite matrix. Can we bound eigenvalues of $S'=DSD$ knowing eigenvalues of $S$? I would like to find a positive upper bound and a positive lower bound in terms of eigenvalues of $S$ and/or $D$.

Comment: Your inequality for the upper-bound does not seem to be correct. Also, what does $i$ means here?

Comment: The matrix $DSD$ behaves "quadratically" with respect to $D,$ so $\mu_i$ should depend quadratically with respect to $D.$ The conclusion fails already for $D=d\,{\rm Id}.$

Comment: You're right! Its was a mistake!